# Case statements in VHDL

Tags: case, vhdl

When programming in VHDL, can you use a variable in a case statement? This variable will modified by one of the cases

i.e.

```
case task is

when 1 =>

when 2 => 

when number =>
```

is this OK?

Comment: Might be worth posting a bit more code so we can see how your proposing to use a variable! If your planning on writing code for synthesis then you must ensure you don't use a variable to maintain state, and its just for a temporary result in a calculation for example.

Comment: @Binary Nerd: Why can't you use variable's to store state???  Standard practice here..

Comment: Ultimately depends on what the OP is trying to achieve, which is a great unknown...  S/he can definitely use a (hopefully registered) variable to maintain state if that's what s/he intends to do.

Answer (score 3):

For simulation or synthesis?

Either way, from the [documentation](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/sequential.html#case):

> The choices must be **constants** of the same discrete type as the expression.

Use `if` to test for `number`, either:

```
if task=number then
  ...
else
  case task is
    when 1 => ...
    when 2 => ...
    when others => ...
  end case;
end if;
```

or

```
case task is
  when 1 => ...
  when 2 => ...
  when others =>
    if task=number then
      ...
    else
      ...
    end if;
end case;
```

Your choice depends on whether you want the result of the `if task=number` test or of the `when ... =>` test to have priority? (e.g. assume that for whatever reason `number=1`, do you want `when 1 =>` or `if task=number` to ultimately provide your result?)

In the trivial case the `case` statement synthesizes as a multiplexer; the `if` statement synthesizes as a comparator and two-input multiplexer.  One feeds into the other.